# E-Visa for Azerbaijan

Tags: visas, transit-visas, azerbaijan, e-visas, austrian-citizens

Instead of getting a visa from an embassy, there is an option to receive an e-visa trough [a government accredited tourist agency](http://mct.gov.az/upload/1455720805e-viza-2016-en.pdf). The main benefit for me besides faster processing and not having to go to an embassy is, that I don't have to provide my passport before entering the country.

There is no fixed fee, some of the webpages don't even provide information on the fee beforehand (you have to query them by e-mail), some sell the e-visa only in combination with compulsory extras (like a 51 dollar Baku walking tour). I tried one webpage, which couldn't process my e-mail (due to a length validation). After creating a new (shorter) one, I struggled to reduce the file size of the required documents enough to not receive a stacktrace from their web aplication only to finally fail during the payment process. At least the payment is handled by a third party, but I still don't feel particularly happy entering personal information on a webpage, which is programmed in such a sloppy way.

The whole process seems a bit of a mess to me, however I don't have enough time to go through the "old school" visa process over an embassy and also need to have my passport available for a different visa application, so I guess I have no other option.

Does anyone has any experience with the Azerbaijani e-visa process and can recommend how one can get it online? I need a transit visa for 2 days and I'm on an Austrian passport.

Comment: Do you want an Azerbaijanian Transit Visa, good for 3 days, for which you need apply at least a week in advance, or an E-Visa, good for up to 30 days, for which you need a confirmed Hotel reservation for the entire period of stay?

Comment: A transit visa would be sufficient. I asked at the embassy, the processing time for a transit is the same as for a regular tourist visa.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but I wanted to add anyway. My passport allows for visa on arrival in Azerbaijan. When I arrived in Baku and went straight to the visa on arrival desk, they asked me to fill in lots of forms and pay the $10 visa fee and wait in line for about 20 minutes. An officer working there silently asked whether I'd pay $20 extra to avoid all that. After I rejected the bribe request, he gave me yet another form to fill in. Long story short, they ask for a bribe everywhere in that country, do whatever you can in advance to avoid those situations.

Comment: As there's now fully centralized government website (the only one) for granting e-visas to Azerbaijan, I've edited the question to nominate it for reopening and then contribute with my answer to it, because now the question is not opinion-based, on the contrary it has a single correct answer, and the previous answers are outdated. If you agree with the edit, please nominate it for reopening, as I have low reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using [Alean Travel Company](http://www.aleantravel.com). We exchanged a couple of e-mails, payment was done via Western Union (USD 55) and the visa arrived two days before my planned entry by e-mail. They also offered me an airport pick-up for USD 15, which I felt was a reasonable price. All in all, everything went smooth and without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

[STI Azerbaijan](http://www.sti.az/), the local representation of the [International Student Travel Confederation](http://www.aboutistc.org/), also offers e-visas. In my experience, their service is friendly and fast.

Comment: STI is your best bet IMO - and you should contact them through this Website http://caravanistan.com/visa/azerbaijan/letter-of-invitation-loi-visa-support/